# How do I run a screen saver as my desktop background?

Tags: customization, screensaver

I would like to run a screen saver as my desktop background.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020824082233907) for instructions.

Essentially, set your preferred screen saver in the Screen Saver preference pane and run this command in the Terminal to see the screen saver on the desktop:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/ScreenSaver.framework/Resources/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &
```

Comment: @duci9y The ampersand is deliberate. It runs the command in the background.

Comment: This hosed my machine (had to hard reboot), on High Sierra