# How to set screensaver as desktop background in Mojave and above

Tags: mojave, catalina, screensaver, multitasking

[High Sierra, how to set screensaver as desktop background?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326759/high-sierra-how-to-set-screensaver-as-desktop-background) explains how to use the Screensaver as an (animated) desktop background. Unfortunately the `-background` option to `/S*/L*/F*/S*/R*/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine` required to make this work isn't supported any more in Mojave and newer versions of macOS.

So how can a screensaver be used as a desktop background in Mojave and above?

Comment: I made a rather heavy handed edit to focus the question on the actual issues. Assumption here is that you are looking for answers, not for further discussions, so describing all the things other people already posted on other sites just adds a lot of complexity to the post.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was saying but our fellow peers where saying i should copy everything here...