# Using a screensaver as a desktop wallpaper?

Tags: catalina, desktop, screensaver, wallpaper

I've looked around a lot for a way to use one of the screensavers as the wallpaper for my desktop. I found a few options but all of them didn't seem to work on macOS Catalina. The way I tried to attempt this was by using the following code.
`/System/Library/CoreServices/ScreenSaverEngine.app/Contents/MacOS/ScreenSaverEngine -background &`

All this does is launch the screensaver, instead of making it my wallpaper. Any way that this could be done on Catalina?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a still image of a certain frame in the screensaver you can do a screenshot of the screensaver at the right time and then use the sceenshot as your desktop.

if you want the running screenshot to be your desktop there was a similar question asked and the [answer is given here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/326759/high-sierra-how-to-set-screensaver-as-desktop-background) for High Sierra and that may apply to Catalina.

Comment: I tried that exact thing but the code `-background` doesn't work in Catalina.